# Add the contents of one file at the end of each line of another file

Tags: python, file, sed

I want to add the contents of a file containing passwords and add it to the other file which contains a list of emails and I want the format to be:

```
email@example.com:examplepass
```

I've tried to do it with a Python script but no luck so far, tried it with sed and it worked, but not what I wanted it to do. I created a new environment variable and I set it up as follows:

```
export FILES=$(cat pass.txt)
```

Then I used the command

```
sed 's/$/$($FILES)/' test.txt > test5000.txt
```

to add each password of each line into the email list, but instead it printed out

```
email@example.com:$FILES
```

Comment: Can you give a small example of both files?

Comment: doesn't seem like a python question. But if you use `$FILES` within simple quotes, that won't be evaluated. You could try `sed 's/\$/\$($FILES)/' test.txt > test5000.txt`

Comment: `man paste`.  Seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "at the end *of each line*"

Comment: Please add both files to your question and your desired output for those files to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you just want `paste -d: test.txt pass.txt`

Answer (score 0):

it works with `sed` but wrapping in single quotes avoids evaluation of the env. variable. So enclose in double quotes instead. Also, no need to repeat the $ in the replacement.

```
sed "s/\$/($FILES)/" test.txt > test5000.txt
```

Warning: There's a good chance that some password characters are interpreted in the replacement (for instance what about backwards references like `\1` or even quotes!!...) so this solution isn't really viable when you don't know what's in `$FILES`

Python version (I recommend this solution), untested but pretty confident about it, and is foolproof, even if the password file contains special chars:

```
with open('pass.txt') as fr:
    passwords = fr.read()
with open("test.txt") as fr, open('test50000.txt', "w") as fw:
   fw.writelines('{}{}\n'.format(t.rstrip(),passwords) for t in fr)
```

first, read the password file, then open input & output and write the lines made of the user name (without line terminator) + password + line terminator in a comprehension for better speed.

Comment: idk about the python but do not use that sed script as it won;t do what you want and if it tried to it'd corrupt your output given various characters in the password file. This is the job `paste` exists to do, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120730/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton I trust your judgement. Trust my judgement about the python code that won't corrupt anything. I'll edit.

Comment: I believe you but what's the point writing a python script to do what `paste file1 file2` does? Or is it doing something different?

Comment: if you're in a python environment already and you want to write portable code (ex: windows) you may want to avoid using external commands.

Comment: fair enough since the OP did tag the question with python and sed but not `unix` or `shell` or anything else that'd generally include `paste` or other UNIX commands.